# Overriding some theme styles and properties per module

Tags: wpf, themes, prism-4, basedon

I am writing a WPF application using "Prism", and some purchased Grid theme is applied "Xceed Theme."  I am designing a huge change required by our customer to give them the option of modifying some properties (like the background of selected row, for example) and this functionality to be available per screen "Module."

So my questions are:

1. After adding my xceed grid theme source to my `App.xaml` merged dictionaries, how can I override some of its styles (that I know the keys of) in another xaml file away from `app.xaml` (possibly by adding `BasedOn` to the `style` tag)?
2. Is it possible to create a custom resource dictionary for each module and add it to the `app.xaml` merged dictionaries while loading?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the style changes in the main window/control's resources within each module. Then the differences would apply to each module separately.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have userd Dynamic Resources. The main project loads the main style. somthing like this :

```
<FontFamily x:Key="ApplicationFontFamily">Tahoma</FontFamily>
```

and in my module i have changed it programmatically :

```
Application.Current.Resources["ApplicationFontFamily"] = new FontFamily("Arial");
```

it worked for me ;)

Comment: what about styles and brushes defined/used internally in templates .. how to achieve it the same way